# No implicit conversion of String into Integer, open date filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, filter, opendata

I'm actually trying to use Json, from open data paris, and to filter some stuff.

I can create what I want with those lines:

```
def import 
@result = ''
url = 'http://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?rows=1000&dataset=arc_innovation&facet=code_postal&facet=commune&facet=etat_1&facet=typologie_carto&facet=type_innovation&facet=image'
response = HTTParty.get(url)
hash = response.parsed_response
hash['records'].each do |record|
  lime = Lime.where(datasetid: record['datasetid'], recordid: record['recordid']).first_or_initialize
  lime.title = record['fields']['nom']
  lime.text = record['fields']['txt_descriptif']
  lime.url = record['fields']['site_internet']
  lime.xy = record['fields']['xy']
  category = category_from_typeinnovation(record['fields']['type_innovation'])
  lime.categories << category unless category.nil?
  if record['fields'].has_key? 'image'
    image_id = record['fields']['image']['id']
    image_filename = record['fields']['image']['filename']
    image_url = "http://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/arc_innovation/files/#{image_id}/download"
    lime.image = image_url
  end

  lime.save
  @result += "imported #{lime.title}\n"
end
render text: @result
end
```

Here is how looks my Json like

```
"records":[
 {
"fields":{
"commune":"Paris 19e",
"code_postal":75019,
"id_formularie":1,
"etat_1":"existant",
"contact_tel":"01 53 35 50 00",
"xy":[
48.889979,
2.371504
],
"nom":"104",
"txt_descriptif":"Plateforme collaborative qui s’intéresse à la création artistique contemporaine dans toute sa diversité, elle accueille des artistes en résidence et accompagne l’émergence de nouvelles formes d’art avec le Cinq destiné aux pratiques amateurs, la Maison desPetits et un incubateur qui héberge et soutient le développement de start-ups.",
 "type_innovation":"Lieux innovants de la culture et du sport",
},
```

I try to filter by "type-innovation". I don't want to create a post with the data that own "type_innovation":"Lieux innovants de la culture et du sport" for example.

I tried to filter like this:

```
def import 
    @result = ''
    url = 'http://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?        rows=1000&dataset=arc_innovation&facet=code_postal&facet=commune&facet=etat_1&facet=typologie_carto&facet=type_innovation&facet=image'
response = HTTParty.get(url)
hash = response.parsed_response
hash['records'].each do |record|
  lime = Lime.where(datasetid: record['datasetid'], recordid: record['recordid']).first_or_initialize
  lime.title = record['fields']['nom']
  lime.text = record['fields']['txt_descriptif']
  lime.url = record['fields']['site_internet']
  lime.xy = record['fields']['xy']
  category = category_from_typeinnovation(record['fields']['type_innovation'])
  lime.categories << category unless category.nil?
  if record['fields'].has_key? 'image'
    image_id = record['fields']['image']['id']
    image_filename = record['fields']['image']['filename']
    image_url = "http://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/arc_innovation/files/#{image_id}/download"
    lime.image = image_url
  end
  if record['fields']['type_innovation'] != ['fields']['type_innovation']['Lieux innovants de la culture et du sport']
  lime.save
  @result += "imported #{lime.title}\n"
end
end
render text: @result
end
```

When I try to import it returns me the error. How Should I do the filtering?

Comment: Please always past the full error message together with a stacktrace. It seems the error might be caused by: `if record['fields']['type_innovation'] != ['fields']['type_innovation']['Lieux innovants de la culture et du sport']`. You forgot to add `record` before `['fields']` hence you are executing `[]` with a string argument on an array. Anyway, it seems that expression after `!=` is entirely wrong, as you just want to compare strings, don't you?

Comment: yes i'd like to compare two strings and to save if they are different